# Why do I get compilation error when doing flatmap() call?

Tags: java-8, java-stream, flatmap

Let's say I have the following object:

```
public class DaylyData {

private Date date;
private List<Integer> numersList;

// standard getters/setters

public Map<Integer, Date> getIntToDate() {
    Map<Integer, Date> resultMap = new HashMap<>();
    for(Integer number : getNumersList()) {
        resultMap.put(number, getDate());
    }
    return resultMap;
}
```

Now, let say I have a list of DaylyData: `List<DaylyData> resultList`.

What will be the result of the following:

```
resultList.stream().flatMap(entity -> entity.getIntToDate());
```

If I assign the result of that to `Stream<Map<Integer, Date>>`, I am getting `Type mismatch: cannot convert from Map<Integer,Date> to Stream<? extends Map<Integer,Date>>`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `flatMap` method is a special case of a `map` and is used for flattening nested `Stream`, `Optional`, and other monadic tools.

In your case, you are not providing a function that returns a `Stream` so it can't be used as `flatMap` param.

Your function will work fine with the standard `map()`, though:

```
resultList.stream()
  .map(entity -> entity.getIntToDate()); // no compilation errors
```

You could make your example work by wrapping the result in a `Stream` instance but this does not give you any advantage over the example above - it makes sense to do that only for educational purposes:

```
resultList.stream()
   .flatMap(entity -> Stream.of(entity.getIntToDate())); // no compilation error
```

---

It's "daily" not "dayly".